# How to sample array from gamma distribution with shape values given by different array in Julia?

Tags: arrays, random, julia, gamma-distribution

In Julia, I have an array of shape values and I would like to sample an array who's values are gamma distributed according to the corresponding shape element of my shape array. What I want is:

```
    shapes = [1.1, 0.5, 10]  
    scale = 1  
    x = SampleGammaWithDifferentShapes(shapes,scale)
```

where `x[1]` is sampled from a gamma distribution with shape=`shapes[1]`, and `x[2]` is sampled from a gamma distribution with shape=`shape[2]`, and so on.

Is there a built in function that allows you to do this in one line or will I have to define my own function for this? This seems like it should be a built in function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The possibility to just broadcast any function over arrays makes it unnecessary to add special array-versions of functions. Can you do it for 1 value? Then just broadcast.

```
using Distributions

shapes = [1.1, 0.5, 10.]
scale = 1
x = rand.(Gamma.(shapes, scale))
```

Comment: That is expected. For each shape, you call `rand(g, 2)` and get an array with 2 random values, and then you broadcast that operation across all shapes. If you wish to flatten this, you can use `vcat(x...)` or `collect(Iterators.flatten(x))`.  (Edit: followup comment disappared and now i look silly)

Comment: Mikael, apologies. I had realized my mistake immediately and removed the comment right away.

Answer (score 3):

The map function is useful for this.

```
using Random, Distributions

shapes = [1.1, 0.5, 10]  
scale = 1
n_samples = 1
x = map(x -> rand(Gamma(x,scale), n_samples)[1], shapes)
```